# How can I get %x in Log4perl to not show "[undef]"?

Tags: perl, log4perl

When I haven't pushed anything to the Log::Log4perl::NDC stack, `%x` returns `[undef]`. I would like it to return an empty string when the stack is empty.

For example, take this code:

```
use strict;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
Log::Log4perl->easy_init({ level => $INFO, layout => "%x %m%n" });
Log::Log4perl->get_logger()->info("first message");
Log::Log4perl::NDC->push("prefix");
Log::Log4perl->get_logger()->info("second message");
```

This prints:

```
[undef] first message
prefix second message
```

But I want it to print:

```
first message
prefix second message
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%x` is explicitly [documented](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log%3A%3ALog4perl%3A%3ANDC) as returning `[undef]` if nothing is on the NDC stack. So with standard `%x` you're out of luck. However, by using a self-defined placeholder and looking into the NDC internals you can format the output like you like, e.g.:

```
Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout::add_global_cspec('U', sub {
    @Log::Log4perl::NDC::NDC_STACK ? join(" ", @Log::Log4perl::NDC::NDC_STACK) . " " : ''
});
```

Then simply use

```
Log::Log4perl->easy_init({ level => $INFO, layout => "%U%m%n" });
```

(note the missing space after %U here).

It would be better if the current NDC_STACK was available by function, or if the existing variables was documented. Maybe ask the log4perl developers if they could do any of both?